# Using the Pi as a remote server via iPhone

Tags: raspbmc

I have a external hard drive connected to my raspberry Pi that contains videos.  Is there a way I can set it up so that I can remotely view these from my iPhone?

Comment: The *DNLA* represents a cross-platform protocol for sharing digital media on a network.  There is at least one DNLA server for raspbian, "miniDNLA" and no doubt oodles of DNLA clients for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view video files in your Raspberry disk from your iPhone, you should install DLNA server onto operating system that runs on Raspberry Pi and DLNA client onto your iPhone.

I can suggest **miniDLNA** as server that @goldilocks suggest too. I assume that youre using Raspbian, so i will tell the Raspbian way of installing miniDLNA.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install minidlna -y
```

After install finished you have to configure the minidlna server. Server uses **/etc/minidlna.conf** file as configuration file.

Open /etc/minidlna.conf and change the media_dir value. (Example of my media folders like below.) Comment default value then add your values. **(A = audio folder, V = Video folder, P = Picture folder)**

```
media_dir=A,/media/MAXTOR/Mp3
media_dir=V,/media/MAXTOR/Movies
media_dir=P,/media/MAXTOR/MyDocs/Photos/
media_dir=V,/media/SAMSUNG/Belgesel
```

You can change listening interface, port, serial number, log level and other parameters in the config file.

Then you have to restart minidlna server with that command.

```
/etc/init.d/minidlna restart
```

On iPhone you can select any minidlna client app to install. I use that one https://itunes.apple.com/TR/app/id410280827?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

After installing the app on iPhone, be sure you're on same wireless network with DLNA server, search the network and find your DLNA server and media folders to view.