# How to Stream Media from Raspberry Pi to iphone/ipad/android?

Tags: raspbmc, wifi, media-server

I've just recently bought a Raspberry Pi with a preinstalled Raspbian 16GB SD Card. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble installing stuff on it, as sometimes the mouse + keyboard combo doesn't work with Wi-Fi, and sometimes the USB Mouse and USB Keyboard don't work with Ethernet. I haven't yet connected to the internet with it. I tried the OS on Windows using an emulator `(qemu)`, so I know how to install basic stuff like `rdesktop` and `remmina`... but since the internet is down, it's pointless to try to do anything on the pi.

Anyways, my question is, once the internet starts working, how can I setup the Pi as a media server? I intend to use it as a media server over local Wi-Fi and not just a HDMI input to the TV, which is what I've read about the XBMC server being used for.

I have a 1 TB external USB hard disc that connects and draws power from the USB source. So I think that the Raspberry Pi might not support it, but I could also buy a 64 GB flash drive if the media server is set up properly.

I checked online for solutions and found two os for pi to support media streaming

[[:: SqueezePlug ::]](http://www.techradar.com/news/digital-home/media-servers/use-raspberry-pi-to-stream-to-any-device-with-squeezeplug-1154688): I don't know about how it will connect to Wi-Fi, otherwise this OS could be a good alternative. It also doesn't have an x-desktop. I.e., no `gui`, I guess, only command line... (presuming this from what I read online).

[[:: Raspbmc ::]](http://www.raspbmc.com/%20RaspBMC) : I'm guessing this is the same as XBMC, but it's only for the Pi. I don't know if it supports streaming over the wifi.

Well, that's mostly all. I was hoping `Squeezeplug` would have a GUI, so that I could also handle stuff like "file server" and `,` etc with it.

Thanks for any help.

-

Comment: try using plex [tutorial here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-plex-server/) i tried this and it works great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explain what streams you thought. If you mean live streams, it's a bit difficult for pi. But if you want to watch movies/clips from your USB disk which is connected to Pi use miniDLNA as @Lawrence mentioned too.

You can connect with DLNA clients which installed on your iPhone/iPad/Android smart phone to miniDLNA server which installed on Pi server if Pi and your smart phone on same network.

You can get help from an old question answered by me : [Using the Pi as a remote server via iPhone](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/using-the-pi-as-a-remote-server-via-iphone/9368#9368)

Basically;
- Install miniDLNA on your OS at Pi.
- Configure miniDLNA to point your media library on USB disk which connected to Pi.
- Install DLNA client on your smart phone.
- Search DLNA servers on your DLNA client
- Enjoy your config.

Comment: Thanks! That could solve the problem, but I haven't tried it yet... I'm trying to find out how to connect between pi and win7 as asked here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9906/unable-to-use-ssh-to-access-pi-over-local-network

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a GUI on the Pi to use it as a normal PC while still using it as a media streaming server, you can install minidlna on the Pi to stream media to other devices.

Comment: does it stream to multiple devices simultaneously?

Comment: It can do. Do you need to stream things simultaneously or On-Demand ?

Comment: Nope, not simultaneously, Need it On Demand.

Comment: Yep, MiniDLNA will suit that perfectly.